# Add object to another list?

Tags: c#

I wonder if it's possible to add an object from one list to another list like this:

```
objectToRemoveList.Add(listOfObjects.ElementAt(i));
```

Then, I want to remove all object in the list like this:

```
objectToRemoveList.Clear();
```

I wonder, because it seems like the objects are still there!?

Comment: Are we talking about plain vanilla `List<T>` lists? If so, then the code you have should work. How are you determining the objects are still there?

Comment: After the call to `objectToRemoveList.Clear();`, the list `objectToRemoveList` is empty. `listOfObjects` was not modified; what exactly would you have expected to happen?

Comment: I'm using this in XNA, and the objects (sprites) are still one the screen. I was not sure about the move of object to another list. Yes it's a plain List<T>

Comment: So you want to add an object just to remove it (with all others)?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Removing objects from a list usually means just that: They are not in the particular list any more. It does *not* mean that the objects themselves get destroyed in any fashion or removed from the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That won't work. Let me explain it in a graphical way. Your objects exist somewhere in memory:

```
  a     b     c     d
```

Your list `listOfObjects` only contains a **reference** to each of these objects:

```
listOfObjects:  |     |     |     |     
                |     |     |     |     
                v     v     v     v     
                a     b     c     d
```

If you add some of these items (let's say `b` and `d`) to `objectToRemoveList`, you are also **only adding a reference**:

```
listOfObjects:  |     |     |     |     
                |     |     |     |     
                v     v     v     v     
                a     b     c     d
                      ^           ^
                      |           |
objToRemoveLst:       |           |
```

By executing `objectToRemoveList.Clear`, you are just removing all references there. Note how `listOfObjects` is completely unafffected:

```
listOfObjects:  |     |     |     |     
                |     |     |     |     
                v     v     v     v     
                a     b     c     d


objToRemoveLst:
```

---

To achieve what you want to do, you can use the following loop:

```
foreach (object o in objectToRemoveList) {
    listOfObjects.Remove(o);
}
```

That way, the references are actually removed from `listOfObjects`, which is what you want:

```
listOfObjects:  |           |           
                |           |           
                v           v           
                a     b     c     d
                      ^           ^
                      |           |
objToRemoveLst:       |           |
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add elements from `listOfObjects` to `objectToRemoveList`, you're only adding a reference to the object to you list, not the object itself (unless your list is of value types, which doesn't seem to be the case). Thus, when you `Clear()` one of the lists, the other list will still contain the original items since you didn't modify them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the objects in the original list will remain unchanged because you are adding a reference of the item at index i. If you have value types then it will create a copy.

Why not do `listOfObjects.RemoveAt(i)` if you want to remove an item from a known index in the original list?

Comment: +1, but just remember to remove the elements in *decreasing* order (e.g. first element 4, then element 2), because otherwise the indexes change.